# Route Not found exception in laravel 5.3 tried resource route and manual route as well

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.3

I created a resource `BrandController` and then made its routes. The problem is that some routes are working and some are not. For example, `create` route is not working. I have also tried it to declare routes manually but problem is same. I ran command like

> php artisan route:clear
>   php artisan cache:clear

**Here are routes**

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'AppControllers'], function () {


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| All routes of BrandController are defined here
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
*/
Route::get('brands', 'BrandController@index')->name('brand.index');
Route::get('brand/create', 'BrandController@create')->name('brand.create');
Route::get('brand/edit/{id}', 'BrandController@edit')->name('brand.edit');
Route::delete('brand/delete/{id}', 'BrandController@destroy')->name('brand.destroy');
Route::post('brand/store', 'BrandController@store')->name('brand.store');
Route::post('brand/update/{id}', 'BrandController@update')->name('brand.update');

// Here is resource route
Route::resource('brands', 'BrandController');
```

});

I have created a simple `a` tag here it is:

```
<a href="{{route('brand.create')}}">Add New</a>
```

Whenever I click on this  link it converts `/` into `dot`like this

> http://localhost:8080/rms/public/brands.create

It also generated

> http://localhost:8080/rms/public/brand/create

But same issue persists. `NotFoundHttpException` in RouteCollection

**Controller Code:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\AppControllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Brand;

class BrandController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //dd('jgh');
        //$brands = brand::all();
        return view('brands.index');
    }
/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
   return redirect('brands.create');
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(BrandRequest $request)
{
    $input          = $request->all();
    $storeBrand     = new Brand();
    $storeBrand->create($input);
    //return redirect->()->back();
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{

}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    $editBrand = Brand::findOrFail($id);
    return view('brands.edit',compact('editBrand'));
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(BrandRequest $request, $id)
{
    $updateBrand    = Brand::findOrFail($id);
    $input          = $request->all();
    $updateBrand->update($input);
    return redirect()->back();
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    $deleteBrand = Brand::findOrFail($id);
    $deleteBrand->delete();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

}

Comment: Try not to group them. you don't need all of that. that way you can eliminate causes that might do this problem. do it like so: delete that group. and use just what you need. tell if that helps.

Comment: it did not work. the issue is laravel is automatically replacing `brand/create` to `brand.create` which is creating problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `create` method like below

```
public function create()
{
   return redirect('brands/create');
}
```

`.` notation not works in `redirect` method...

Comment: Thanks a ton man. A silly mistake done by me. I was assuming that something is wrong. i had to return `view` instead of `redirect` Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Make your resource routes like this

```
Route::resource('brand', 'BrandController', [
            'names' => [
                'index'=>'brand.list',
                'create'=>'brand.create',
                'store'=>'brand.store',
                'update'=>'brand.update',
                'edit'=>'brand.edit',
                'show'=>'brand.show',
                'destroy'=>'brand.remove',
            ]
        ]);
```

Comment: It did not help. The same issue persists. I also checked it before. but no luck

Comment: So can you show your controllers folder and routes folder structure?

Comment: `routes` folder contains `web.php , api.php and console.php` and controller is resource controller generated via `php artisan make:controller --resource`

Comment: In this case why are you using namespace AppControllers?Remove Route::group from your web.php file and write resource route outside of that group.I have changed my answer copy and past it inside your web.php file.

Comment: I have made a directory `AppControllers` That is why i am using the namespace and i added the `Controller code` kindly have a look at it.

Comment: And one more thing. If namespace is issue then howcome `index` route can work. Store route is also working fine

Comment: For me it look`s prefect and this structure for declaring resource controller working fin on my projects.So I hope you`ll find the issue you need and will send that issue to me.Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Your can use:

`public function create()
{
   return redirect()->route('brands.create');
}`
Or
`public function create()
{
   return redirect('brands/create');
}`

But I am suggesting you use the first one because in that we are using route name in that. if you want to change url them you don't have to worry about this code.